# Javascript syntax: const {Observables} = rxjs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax, rxjs, observable

Can anyone explain for me, what the code below means:

```
const {Observables} = rxjs
```

thank you so much!

Comment: [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have two objects person1 and person2 and we have function displayPerson.
instead of passing using person.age and person.name, we can destructure them using this line.

```
   const { age, name } = person;
```

Below is an example.

```js
  
person1 = { age: 30, name : "James" }
person2 = { age: 32, name : "Kelly" }


displayPerson = (person) => { 
  const { age, name } = person ; 
  console.log(name + " is " + age.toString() + " years old.")
}


displayPerson(person1)
displayPerson(person2)
```